# how to create template suggestion for image like image--NODE-TYPE--VIEW-MODE

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to create a suggestion like image--NODE-TYPE--VIEW-MODE, but in `mytheme_theme_suggestions_image_alter()` $vars i haven't node related info
[image]

thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  When asking questions, please cut-and-paste your code and then mark it with code tags instead of taking a screenshot and uploading that.  Code pasted as text is searchable and helps people find your question when they search.

Answer (score 2):

In the [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.9.x) the `$variables` contain only informations about the theme of entity in this case theme image:
From documentation:

> array $variables: An array of variables passed to the theme hook. Note that this hook is invoked before any preprocessing.

if you look at [`image_theme`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_theme/8.9.x) you can find all variables passed `uri`, `title` ...

So to access node related info you can use route params like the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEME_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $suggestions [] = "image__" . $node->bundle();
}
```

**Note:** you can't access to **View mode** in this hook because it's not in the **`$variables`** and also ***`the current view mode is not stored in the node object`***

Take a look at this issue [Make the current view mode available on the node object](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1339870)

Comment: Will this work when you're displaying a node somewhere other than the canonical node route?